# How to match the class name from an array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have stored all classes an array. And also i added one attribute an element, that is also included an array. I want to add attribute value as class on triggered element. How to implement this logic?

```
var $coverPosition = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom', 'centerxy']
$('.posRow').on('click', function(){
  $('.coverBg').removeClass($coverPosition).addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

My html structure is,

```
<div class="coverBg left">
</div>
<a href="#" class="posRow" data-class="top">
</a>
```

Sometimes coverBg element class may be 'left right'

Comment: Do you wanna do it for all the array classes?

Comment: No. I want to delete that particular class from array. Attribute value and array value may be same @PraveenKumar

Comment: Okay, check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this way, if you wanna do it for all the classes in the array:

```
var $coverPosition = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom', 'centerxy']
$('.posRow').on('click', function(){
  $('.coverBg').removeClass($coverPosition.join(" ")).addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

Comment: 'left, right, top, bottom, centerxy' is this gonna work ?

Comment: @ebilgin woopsie! Updating.

Comment: @PraveenKumar. My trigger element is '.posRow'

Comment: @Sathya Now can you please share the HTML and show what should happen in a better description?

Comment: @Sathya Checked it. Check out my updated answer please. Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: @PraveenKumar. I have updated my question. Please check now.

Comment: @Sathya I just updated my answer. Have a look please?

Comment: @PraveenKumar its working fine. But left class not removing. Its still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90896/discussion-between-sathya-and-praveen-kumar).